# Partial response in jetty REST service

Tags: java, json, rest, embedded-jetty

I am using Jetty embedded 9.2.9, under CentOS with Jersey 2.x
I have REST resource that should result a large JSON (approx 200K)

When requesting from server machine to itself localhost:8080/myresource all works ok
When requesting myip.address:8080/myresource from other machine the json is get cut and when debugged it I see that class org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingCallback#block is throwing IOEXception that state is null

Looks like something in timing to me.

```
Jun 22, 2015 1:14:21 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder writeResponse
SEVERE: An I/O error has occurred while writing a response message entity to the container output stream.
org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.MappableException: java.io.IOException
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:571)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:378)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:368)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at com.liveperson.messaging.async.cm.utils.RequestManipulationFilter.doFilter(RequestManipulationFilter.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at com.liveperson.messaging.async.cm.utils.GKFilter.doFilter(GKFilter.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingCallback.block(BlockingCallback.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:308)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:229)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:230)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:129)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StringMessageProvider.writeTo(StringMessageProvider.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.StringMessageProvider.writeTo(StringMessageProvider.java:59)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:88)
    ... 40 more
```

Help anyone?

Thanks....

Comment: I have a similar problem. I get the same Exception. But when running in jetty 9.2.15 (locally) or Tomcat 8.0.14 (locally) I have no problems. But when deployed in another machine, I get the Exception. Using Jersey 2.22.2 here.